# i hav php5.2.9 +mysql5.1+apache2.2.6 installed on win xp .iam not able get php connect with mysql 

Tags: php, mysql

i have php5.2.9 +mysql5.1+apache2.2.6 installed on win xp. I'm  not able get php connect with mysql. here is the code.`

```
<? php 
$link=mysql_connect('localhost','root','godismine');

if(!$link) 
echo "fail"; 

else echo "success"; 

mysql_close(); 
 ?>
```

i don't think there is any error in code. phpinfo is showing mysql support so it cant be installation issue.
iam jst not able get the prob. whenever i run this script i just get a blank screen.
please help. iam new in php .

Comment: Is the space in `<?php` really intended? If so, remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Let MySQL *tell* you what the error is...

```
<?php 
$link=mysql_connect('localhost','root','godismine');
```

if(!$link) {
  echo "fail ";
  echo 'and the error message is: '.[mysql_error()](http://php.net/mysql_error);
}
else {
  echo "success"; 
  mysql_close($link);
}

Answer (score 0):

Did you create users/grant rights in the database as well? In any case, connecting as root is not really a good idea.